# Having trouble iterating over different conditions

Tags: python, function, loops, debugging

I am having trouble with a function I'm trying to debug. The goal is to be able to read a text file and give the counts of e's where the output of `count_letter_e()` is `TT TF FT FF` with the following conditions:

TT = Count with ignore_accents=True, ignore_case=True
TF = Count with ignore_accents=True, ignore_case=False
FT = Count with ignore_accents=False, ignore_case=True
FF = Count with ignore_accents=False, ignore_case=False

As the function is now, the output successfully gives `TT`. How can I get it to iterate over `TF FT FF` as well?

```
def count_letter_e(loc, ignore_accents = True, ignore_case = True):
    with open(loc+".txt", encoding = "utf-8") as test_file:
        text = test_file.read()
    e_list = ['e', 'é', 'ê', 'è', 'E', 'É', 'Ê', 'È'] # list of e's to look for
    letter_counts = [text.count(e) for e in e_list]
    sum_counts = 0

    for ell in text:
        if ignore_case and ignore_accents:
            text = text.lower()
            sum_counts = sum(letter_counts)
        elif ignore_case == True and ignore_accents == False:
            e_counts = [letter_counts[ell] for ell in e_list]
            sum_counts = sum(e_counts)
        elif ignore_case == False and ignore_accents == True:
            e_counts = [letter_counts[ell] for ell in e_list]
            sum_counts = sum(e_counts)
        elif ignore_case == False and ignore_accents == False:
            count = text.count('e')
    return(sum_counts)
```

Comment: So, how do you normally iterate over anything?

Comment: I would imagine a for statement vs the if/elifs that are currently in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence of combination so the value and iterate over them.

Here's what I mean. Disclaimer: I don't know if it produces the right answer because I don't understand everything going on within the inner-most loop you have (and am too lazy to try to figure/straighten it out).

```
T, F = True, False  # Aliases

def count_letter_e(loc):
    with open(loc+".txt", encoding = "utf-8") as test_file:
        text = test_file.read()

    e_list = ['e', 'é', 'ê', 'è', 'E', 'É', 'Ê', 'È'] # list of e's to look for
    letter_counts = [text.count(e) for e in e_list]
    sum_counts = 0

    for ignore_accents, ignore_case in ((T, T), (T, F), (F, T), (F, F)):
        for ell in text:
            if ignore_case and ignore_accents:
                text = text.lower()
                sum_counts = sum(letter_counts)
            elif ignore_case == True and ignore_accents == False:
                e_counts = [letter_counts[ell] for ell in e_list]
                sum_counts = sum(e_counts)
            elif ignore_case == False and ignore_accents == True:
                e_counts = [letter_counts[ell] for ell in e_list]
                sum_counts = sum(e_counts)
            elif ignore_case == False and ignore_accents == False:
                count = text.count('e')
    return sum_counts

print(count_letter_e('sample_e_input'))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I incorporate inside the function though instead of looping outside of it?

Comment: I did it that way because you were passing `ignore_accents` and `ignore_case` as arguments to the function. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would first count the number of the different types of 'e' separately, and then add the numbers corresponding to the combinations 'TT', 'TF', ....

Something like this:

```
def count_letter_e(text):

    e_lists = {}
    e_lists["lowercase"]        = ['e']
    e_lists["lowercase_accent"] = ['é', 'ê', 'è']
    e_lists["uppercase"]        = ['E']
    e_lists["uppercase_accent"] = ['É', 'Ê', 'È']

    letter_counts = {}
    for e_type, letters in e_lists.items():
        letter_counts[e_type] = 0
        for letter in letters:
            letter_counts[e_type] += text.count(letter)

    sum_count = {}
    sum_count['TT'] = letter_counts['lowercase'] \
                      + letter_counts['lowercase_accent'] \
                      + letter_counts['uppercase'] \
                      + letter_counts['uppercase_accent']
    sum_count['TF'] = letter_counts['lowercase'] \
                      + letter_counts['lowercase_accent']
    sum_count['FT'] = letter_counts['lowercase'] \
                      + letter_counts['uppercase']
    sum_count['FF'] = letter_counts['lowercase']

    return sum_count


if __name__ == "__main__":

    text = "e éêè EE ÉÊÈÉÊÈ"

    counts = count_letter_e(text)
    for e_type, count in counts.items():
        print(e_type, count)
```

The output:

```
FF 1
TF 4
FT 3
TT 12
```